# How to use *this* in a javascript onlick function and traverse with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know if this is possible but I'm trying to use `this` in an onclick javascript function in order to traverse in jquery.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" />
<button onclick="javascript:$.addItem(this)">Add</button>
```

**JS**

```
$.addItem= function(e) {
   var n = parseFloat($(e).siblings('input').val());
};
```

Is this even possible or am I missing something?

Comment: How about just using proper event handlers instead

Comment: @adeneo  yes, I would do that but I wanted to take the opportunity to learn something new..

Comment: That's not how it's done; you can use .on() or .click() If what you're trying to do seems hard then you're doing it wrong; that's what I learned.

Comment: This isn't really something that's worth learning, as it's not very useful and should generally be avoided, but yes, you can pass `this` to the function.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6ySC9/

Comment: Haven't you tried your code before asking the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no point in putting the function in the jQuery object, just declare a regular function.

```
function addItem(e) {
  var n = parseFloat($(e).siblings('input').val());
};
```

Don't use the `javascript:` protocol in an event handler attribute. That's used when you put code in an `href` of a link.

```
<input type="text" />
<button onclick="addItem(this);">Add</button>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/q8b4e/

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use both **event** and **this** like this:

**html**

```
<input type="text" />
<button onclick="javascript:$.addItem(this,event)">Add</button>
```

**JS**:

```
$.addItem= function(elemnt, evnt) {
 alert(evnt);
  //var n = parseFloat($(e).siblings('input').val());
 };
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8maNh/)